# How check a field in a table already exist, in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to add electric appliance details to the table.
Then I want to check electric appliance is already exist or not. If already exist give an error message , not insert data to the table.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (textBox4.Text != "" & textBox5.Text != "" & textBox13.Text != "" & dateTimePicker1.Text != "")
      {
          con.Open();
          if(textBox13.Text == "Fan")
          {
             cmd.CommandText = "select * from Appliance_Location where Appliance_Id = '" + textBox4.Text + "'";
             cmd.Connection = con;
             //con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already Exist", "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);  
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Appliance_Location(Appliance_Id, RoomId,ApplianceName,AddDate) values ('" + textBox4.Text + "' ,'" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox13.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "');Update Appliance_Count set Fan = Fan + 1 where RoomId = '" + textBox5.Text + "' ";
                // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("New Fan added !", "Add Appliance", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                con.Close();

                textBox4.Text = "";
                textBox5.Text = "";
                textBox13.Text = "";
                dateTimePicker1.Text = ""; 
            }
                //loadtable();
        }
     }
```

I just tried with this code . But data not insert to the table.

[image]

Comment: you've commented out executing the insert

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you start looking into `Stored Procedures` instead of using `dynamic sql`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you calling `SqlCommand.Clone()`?  You're not actually executing your query, you're just opening and closing your connection.

You've commented out the line of code that needs to be executed:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Without actually executing the query, you're virtually doing nothing (no data modifications).

**Edit**

As per your comment, you're getting an error that there's already an open data reader.  You would need to call `SqlDataReader.Close()` to get around that issue.

**But there is no real reason to *use* a data reader** to just test for the existence of data (in order to determine if you need to insert the row).  Just do a `select count(*) ...` instead:

```
         cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Appliance_Location where Appliance_Id = '" + textBox4.Text + "'";
         cmd.Connection = con;
         con.Open();
         int rowCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (rowCount == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already Exist", "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);  
        }
```

## SUPER IMPORTANT !!!!

*You are leaving yourself open to one of the most common forms of hack/attack: SQL injection*

You need to parameterize your SQL query to prevent SQL injection:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Appliance_Location where Appliance_Id = @ApplicationId;";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ApplicationId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32) { Value = textBox4.Text });
```

The above code is assuming your `ApplicationId` column is of type `varchar(32)`, but please adjust appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your response.                                                                                          I removed the comment , but then error occured  "There is already an open datareader associted with this command which must be closed first "

Comment: @kandegerajika I've modified my answer.  It's because you haven't closed our your `SqlDataReader` object.  But you really don't need to use a data reader object just to get row count.  My answer shows some modified logic.

Comment: @kandegerajika I've added onto my answer.  You need to parameterize your SQL queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @kandegerajika You're quite welcome. I do urge you to take my advice about the SQL injection, though, that is a quite serious security hole.